# Vbscript: 'manually' open a new Excel workbook while the script is running an Excel in the background

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I developed a couple of Excel macro's to modify data obtained from a log and to write the result to an SQL database. I'm also using a vbscript in order to run this Excel (and its macro's) in the background and to periodically write away the data without bothering the user. The vbscript contains the following code:

```
Dim objExcel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'C:\Users\W**\**\SQL.xlsm'!ThisWorkbook.workbook_open"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
WScript.Sleep 60000
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

This works perfectly. However, there is one issue. It seems impossible to **open** another workbook while the Excel is being executed in the background. Does anyone know whether and how this problem can be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/doevents-function?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), this might help

Comment: You can't open another workbook from your script, or interactively from Excel?

Comment: I can't open another workbook interactively. Opening any Excel-file myself while the script is active does not work. 

For instance, when the script (and Excel) are executed in the background. It should be possible for users to open and work with Excel like they would normally. However, now they're not able to open any existing or new files.

Answer (score 0):

After line `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, put

```
objExcel.Visible = False
```

This will force Excel to spawn a new instance when started interactively.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this already and it doesn't quite solve the problem. If an instance is active before starting the script, a new instance is started correctly when the script is ran. However, if the instance of the script is the only one active, it remains impossible to open any other existing/new workbooks.

Comment: Just for the record, my test went as follows: prepared a dummy workbook with code to sleep for 30 seconds; closed Excel; launched the vbs; waited 5 seconds; launched Excel manually and opened another workbook without issues. Maybe it has to do with the way you launch Excel manually, e.g. are you double-clicking on an Excel file from File Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same problem, it seems that I have found a working solution after some more trial and error.

Adding the following statement in the very beginning to create a second instance appears to resolve all issues:

```
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```